# Using XTempate with Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

So working though the mostly absent docs on templates - unable to get it to work.

```
Ext.define('MyAPp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'welcomeLogin',
    config: {
        html: 'This shows',
        tpl:   Ext.create ('Ext.XTemplate', '<div>Please show something</div>', {
            compiled: true
       })
     }

});
```

Why does the template content now show?  I have tried adding apply(), applyTemplate() on and on and on...  Please help!!!

Comment: Did you tried not having an html property and having a data property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ilija139 is right.
you need to define the data property, even if it's empty.

```
data: {}
```

Edit:
Also, the `compile` attribute isn't needed. It only applies to Ext.Templates not XTemplates (according to the docs). Works the same for me without `compile`